# phpmyadmin / create table / syntax error / enum

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, phpmyadmin

> I have searched, but frustratingly have been unable to figure out why I am getting this error on the following SQL statement.

Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''kidney_renal_dialysis' enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL, 'liver_c' at line 5

SQL Statement:>

```
CREATE TABLE `client_health_info` (
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `ER_visits_3_months` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `hospitilizations_last_year` int(2) NOT NULL,
  'kidney_renal_dialysis' enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,
  'liver_cirr_ES_liver' enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,   
  'HCAH' enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,
  'hiv_aids' enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB not CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes! ;-)

```
CREATE TABLE `client_health_info` (
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `ER_visits_3_months` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `hospitilizations_last_year` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `kidney_renal_dialysis` enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,
  `liver_cirr_ES_liver` enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,   
  `HCAH` enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL,
  `hiv_aids` enum('Yes','UnderTreat','No','Ref') not NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB, CHARSET=latin1;
```

**EDIT:** Fixed two further bugs: Duplicate `PRIMARY KEY` statement and the `NOT` before `CHARSET`.